# Programatically get next value for primary key when IDENTITY is set to OFF

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

My table primary key is set to be `[Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]`

I want to copy records into a new row with a new primary key, is there a best way to do this other than taking the max value and adding 1

Comment: Depends how you're copying them. Whatever you do here though, you *will* have to increment the ID by 1 each time. Pretty unavoidable.

Comment: The best way would be to **use `IDENTITY`** - anything else is a manual hack, prone to duplicates and other issues. Don't waste your time on this - let the database handle this detail for you - it does so very effectively and efficiently - don't re-invent the wheel !

Comment: I don't know about EF but with TSQL would use output clause.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest to set **IDENTITY to On for batter maintainability**. But if you cant sent it then there are two suggestions :

**1. set Datatype as UniqueIdentifier :**

You can set the data type of your primary key to UniqueIdentifier and assign value to the primary key from code behind as mentioned below :

```
var newId = Guid.NewGuid();
```

**2. Get Max ID before insertion:**

If UniqueIdentifier is not the solution then get Max value from your primary key and set **Max Value + 1** as your next id as mentioned below :

```
var maxId = this.DataContext.[TableName].Max(table => table.[PK_Column]);
var newId = maxId + 1;
```

Comment: We should note here that the second method will only work if you do not delete rows from the db. The maximum value in the PK column will be the highest value of existing lines only and not necessarily the next PK the SQL agent will use (higher values might have existed in the past, but won't get used)

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is try and make your key as unique as possible. That is kind of the idea with the unique identifier of sql. Possibly using the ticks of datetime or something like that.

I still think this is a hack, and should be a last resort.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem but i did not need a second id field. My primary id was already a guid but the client wanted a number field for the contactId to display in the application. Seems to work great because we do not delete any entities just mark them as isActive = false so no fear of repeating numbers.

Base Entity class

```
public virtual void PrepareSave(EntityState state)
{
    var identityName = Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name;
    var now = DateTime.UtcNow;

    if (state == EntityState.Added)
    {
        CreateBy = identityName ?? "unknown";
        CreateDate = now;
    }

    LastModifedBy = identityName ?? "unknown";
    LastModifed = now;
}
```

I added this to the single entity that need that requirement

```
public override void PrepareSave(EntityState state)
{
    var context = new DbContext();
    var maxId = context.Contacts.Max(model => model.ContactId);
    ContactId = maxId + 1;
    context.Dispose();

    var identityName = Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name;
    var now = DateTime.UtcNow;

    if (state == EntityState.Added)
    {
        CreateBy = identityName ?? "unknown";
        CreateDate = now;
    }

    LastModifedBy = identityName ?? "unknown";
    LastModifed = now;
}
```

In the Datacontext I also added this

```
public override async Task<int> SaveChangesAsync()
    {
        var modifiedEntries = ChangeTracker.Entries()
            .Where(x => x.State == EntityState.Added || x.State == EntityState.Modified);

        foreach (var entry in modifiedEntries)
        {
            // try and convert to an Auditable Entity
            var entity = entry.Entity as BaseEntity;
            // call PrepareSave on the entity, telling it the state it is in
            entity?.PrepareSave(entry.State);
        }

        var result = await base.SaveChangesAsync();
        return result;
    }
```

This was based on the answer marked as correct above SpiderCode Thanks for the suggestion worked great for me ...